# dropping first two rows of every csv files before concatenating them Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4000 csv files that I want to concatenate with equal number of columns. The problem is that they all have column names. I want to remove the first two rows of every csv file and concatenate them. Concatenating them first and dropping the rows with column names using the following code means I lose 4000  rows of data and that will affect my data.

```js
df = pd.read_csv('Concatenated.csv',delimiter=',')
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',)).dropna()
df = df.astype(int)
```

I usually use windows command prompt to combine all the files with `copy *.csv concatenated.csv` and have learned `more +X [file_containing data] > [file_to_export_data_to]` deletes the first x rows of a file. But how do I apply this to all 4000 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [read the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) you'll see that `pandas.read_csv` has an optional parameter `skiprows` which does what you need.

The following code will create a dataframe from the content of the `my-file.csv` without a header and skips the first two rows of the file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my-file.csv', sep=',', header=None, skiprows=2)
```